# how do I get the audio to work from HDMI

Tags: sound

I am using an Atomic Pi SBC running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Bonic. connected to cheap Wal-Mart TV via HDMI cable. Picture is fine but no audio...any ideas?

thanks, Gene

Comment: Audio over HDMI seems to have been an error for a while. In settings>audio>output, does it show any HDMI output as an option?

Comment: Does any other device, using the same HDMI cable, successfully send audio as well as video to the TV?

Comment: I could setup say a DVD player and try it but the TV is brand new...

Comment: under the AUDIO tab it does not list HDMI as a selection....maybe that's the problem. In that case I would need code to accomplish this!!

Comment: I did set the TV as a "TV" and received several channels--with audio.

Comment: I saw that other people upgraded the OS and that solved it.  I ran LUbuntu 19.10 from USB and audio worked on it.